# Mouse over hint for pronoun

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Some concerns about pronounce in the new CoC involve workflow -- i.e., the need to go to a profile page to learn how someone chooses to be addressed.

I notice that reputation pops up as a hint during mouseover of user names in comments.  Does it make sense to include a field for pronoun preference in profiles, and add that field, if not blank, to the mouseover hint?  I think this would improve workflow (though not on tablets).

Comment: I'm not a computer person.  Feel free to edit if my terminology is wrong.

Comment: Honestly, I think this whole issue needs *less* emphasis, not more.

Comment: Note that there has already been fear of profiling and harming users based on their gender identity. Putting that in a specific field will make that a lot easier.

Comment: Worth noting this would only work on comments, not on question or answer authors, so in most case this would still require a trip to the profile page.

Comment: @ErikA: How does surfacing someone's gender more explicitly *reduce*  fear of profiling and harming users based on their gender identity?

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's the opposite of my point. It makes it easier to profile them, so makes this fear more realistic/is a bad idea.

Comment: @ErikA: Oh, I see.  Sorry, I misread.

Comment: I am sensitive to creating another class of user based on gender preference.  I don't have the web skills to know how hard it would be to suck the info out of the mouseover field.  My assumption (correct if wrong) is that if there's pronoun info in the profile, it's perfectly findable wherever it appears (and that playing hide and seek with the info in the profile to make it unfindable doesn't make sense).

Comment: "My assumption (correct if wrong) is that if there's pronoun info in the profile" Only if someone decides to put it there, there is no actual area to put pronouns and it is not required to do so.

Comment: @MarkKirby  same situation if someone decides to leave a field blank.

Comment: There is no field, there is just a box where people can write whatever they like (within reason) I don't understand the point you are tring to make.

Comment: @ScottSeidman: There are no technical hurdles to this; it's perfectly feasible.  The hurdles are social, not technological.

Comment: @MarkKirby I'll drop it, but I was responding to the issue put forth that creating such a field will make people less safe than current practice.  I disagree, as the data is easy enough to mine in the present situation.  If I put my social security number in an about me field, it's not safe just because the field isn't labeled "SSN"

Comment: OK that's fine but I think you meant to respond directly to Erik, rather than just generally to the thread, that is where I got confused. Erik is the one who raised the issue.

Comment: @RobertHarvey  -- actually, I completely missed the 7th or 8th edit of the FAQ on the CoC change, in which the powers that be specify that Profile checks would be best practice, but not required.  I got fixated on the workflow issues, assuming that to stay in compliance, profile checks would be assumed going forward.

Comment: @ScottSeidman: I understand.  This whole thing is confusing for *everyone.*

Comment: @ScottSeidman you might be interested in the [Pronoun Assistant](https://stackapps.com/q/8440/34061) userscript (disclaimer: I'm one of the authors).

Answer (score 11):

This doesn't give any value to the sites as a whole. Just more headache for the engineers for a feature based on a policy that already has serious issues with the community.